# How do I use the states API in a hook?

Tags: 8, forms, javascript

I'm trying to use the states API in Drupal 8 but I'm having trouble, and I'm also having difficult debugging.

Use case:

On user accounts, I have a taxonomy term reference field called **Gender**.  The three terms in the taxonomy vocabulary are female, male, and other.

I also have a text field on user accounts called **Other**.  I want to show this **Other** field if and only if **Gender** is set to *other* (term ID: 27).

Here is the code I'm using:

```
function mymodule_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['field_gender_other']['#states'] = array('visible' =>
    array('input[name="field-gender"]' => array('value' => '27'),
    ),
  );
}
```

I based this off of code I used for Drupal 7.  Unfortunately, it's not doing anything.

I looked at `StateDemo.php` in the fapi submodule of the Examples module for Drupal 8, but that's for building a new form, and I'm trying to modify an existing form.

Comment: Have you debugged the code to see that this function is being hit?

Comment: Is that taxonomy term is select list or autocomplete?

Comment: @AAjayReddy Taxonomy term is in a select list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use code similar to the following one.

```php
$form['field_popin_text']['#states'] = [
  'visible' => [
    'select[name="NAME_OF_SELECT_LIST"]' => ['value' => '27'],
  ]
];
```

Comment: Thanks, I had the `select` wrong and I was also using a `-` in the list name when I should have been using a `_`.

Answer (score 2):

I use this to display or hide fields with dependency in a dropdown select list.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'node_CONTENT_TYPE_form' || $form_id == 'node_CONTENT_TYPE_edit_form') {
    conditional_field_select(
      $form,
      'field_target',
      'field_controller',
      ['value_a', 'value_b', 'value_c'],
      'visible'
    );
  }
}

function conditional_field_select(array &$form, $targetField, $controlledBy, array $values, $state = 'invisible', $cond = 'or') {
  if (isset($form[$targetField]) && isset($form[$controlledBy])) {
    $form[$targetField]['#states'][$state] = [];
    foreach ($values as $value) {
      array_push($form[$targetField]['#states'][$state], ['select[name=' . $controlledBy . ']' => ['value' => $value]]);
      if (end($values) !== $value) {
        array_push($form[$targetField]['#states'][$state], $cond);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It can easily be changed to input.

```
array_push($form[$targetField]['#states'][$state], [':input[name=' . $controlledBy . ']' => ['value' => $value]]);
```